# Como calcular a diferença em horas entre duas datas PHP

Tags: php

Tenho duas datas no formato yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss

A data de entrada "$dataE" e 
a data de saída "$dataS", tem o objetivo de guardar a data de entrada de um funcionário e a data de saída. Até aqui está tudo bem, agora falta ir buscar esses dois valores "$dataE" e "$dataS" e fazer a diferença para saber as horas totais de trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $start  = new \DateTime( '2017-01-9 10:00:00' );
    $end    = new \DateTime( '2018-02-10 11:39:37' );

    $interval = $start->diff( $end );

    echo implode(",", [
        $interval->y . " anos",
        $interval->m . " meses",
        $interval->d . " dias",
        $interval->h . " horas",
        $interval->i . " minutos",
        $interval->s . " segundos",
    ]);

    echo "Diferença em Horas é : " . ($interval->h + ($interval->days * 24));
```

Irá exibir:

```
    1 anos,1 meses,1 dias,1 horas,39 minutos,37 segundos
    Diferença em Horas é : 9529
```

Comment: A minha dificuldade está na parte de ir buscar uma data já inserida, ou seja a parte "$start  = new \DateTime( '2017-01-9 10:00:00' );" não estou a conseguir ir buscar a data que foi inserida no form para substituir a parte "2017-01-9 10:00:00", mas está a guardar a data de saida e de entrada na base de dados